# Getting the data from backend to display it on Front end in X-CART

Tags: module, x-cart

I am working on a X-Cart Module. I need the backend configuration values to the front end. In admin/configuration file I have created an array which contains the value which I need to use it in adv_search.php which is in the root folder. I don't know how to pass that array to adv_search.php.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear how you store the configuration values. It may be easier to store them in the table xcart_config and access them directly as $config['Option-category']['option_name'] in php files and {$config.Option-category.option_name} in the Smarty-templates.

Or just define an array in module's config.php file and this array will be available everywhere in php-scripts. Look at the modules/UPS_OnLine_Tools/config.php file for example.